# printf / _vsnprintf_l / already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, printf, lnk2019, lnk2005, msvcr120.dll

I have project where I want to import library. When I do that (import .lib files from library) and than call any function from library I get following errors:

```
      "C:\Uz\myproj.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->(Link target) ->
    aziotsharedutil.lib(consolelogger.obj) : error LNK2005: printf already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) [C:\Uz\myproj.vcxproj]
    aziotsharedutil.lib(socketio_win32.obj) : error LNK2005: _vsnprintf_l already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) [C:\Uz\myproj.vcxproj]
    uamqp.lib(amqpvalue_to_string.obj) : error LNK2005: _vsnprintf_l already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) [C:\Uz\myproj.vcxproj]
    C:\Dz\myproj.vcxproj\myproj.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found [C:\Uz\myproj.vcxproj]
```

0 Warning(s)
   4 Error(s)

Does anyone know how can i fix this?
I have following libraries imported in my project:

**msvcprtd.lib**

```
msvcrtd.lib
kernel32.lib
ole32.lib
aziotsharedutil.lib    //imported Library .lib file
uamqp.lib              //imported Library .lib file
eventhub_client.lib    //imported Library .lib file
Advapi32.lib
Crypt32.lib
Ws2_32.lib
Secur32.lib
ucrt.lib
vcruntime.lib
```

**Note 1**

All 3 projects that are built as Static Link Library .lib, have same settings Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), same as my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled with same version of compiler and that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this problem and losing their mind - here's an anecdote.

In my particular case, gawk sources refused to build under MSVC with this very error, until I added `#include <stdio.h>` as the first line of `pc/regex.c`.

- I excluded the source files from the build to isolate which source caused it. Many files may seemed to be "affected", but in the end excluding
  `pc/regex.c`
- Since "printf and friends" seemed to be affected, I thought that perhaps something later in the file was clashing. I added `#include <stdio.h>` at the very beginning of the file, before other includes, and that at least worked around the problem.

I did not investigate further at the moment.